# Sub folders and how to namespace classes

Tags: 8

In Drupal 7 I can have a module inside another module. Is this still the case in Drupal 8 and how would I namespace classes inside the sub module?

Another thing I can do in Drupal 7 is to create sub folders inside the modules folder to group my modules.

Example:

sites
--- / all
--- / --- / modules
--- / --- / --- / Collection_Alpha
--- / --- / --- / --- / module_a
--- / --- / --- / --- / module_b
--- / --- / --- / Collection_Beta
--- / --- / --- / --- / module_x
--- / --- / --- / --- / module_y

Is this still possible in Drupal 8? If yes, how would I have to namespace my classes so the autoloader can resolve it to the correct folder structure?

e.g.: Drupal\Collection_Alpha\module_a\myClass1 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure namespace resolution will be registered as "/path/to/module/src", so you shouldn't need to do anything different for the 'sub' modules. i.e. main module will be `Drupal\my_module` in 'my_module/src', sub module will be `Drupal\my_submodule` in 'my_module/modules/my_submodule/src', and so on

Comment: Thanks Clive, that makes sense! What about sub folders? Any idea if this is still supported and how that would look like with autoloading a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Clive is correct.

The namespace is *always* `Drupal\{module_name}`. Where that module lives is irrelevant (as long as it is somewhere where Drupal can find it). That namespace always points to `$path_to_module/src`.

It would not possibly work in any other way. Different sites have modules in a different structure and different places, but the same code has to work no matter where.

Comment: Thanks Clive and Berdir! I guess I have one more follow up question: Is it possible to register an additional namespace which points to the modules folder as well? e.g.: DrupalModules\{module_name} to point to $path_to_module/src? I am asking to better understand how to design our classes today to have little friction when moving to D8 one day.

Comment: If the classes are Drupal-specific (i.e. you're not writing a standalone library), it would arguably be better to keep them under `\Drupal` for consistency's sake. But interesting question nonetheless, I'd encourage you to ask it as a separate question. In fact if you don't, I probably will :)

Comment: You probably could, yes, see system_register() and drupal_classloader_register(). Those helper functions hardcode "Drupal\", but you could get the class_loader service directly. But as @Clive said, I would not recommend doing it, there isn't really a reason to do so, unless you're including an external library.

Comment: Coolio, that makes sense! Thanks guys! @Clive: As you suggested I created http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142309/in-drupal-8-can-i-register-an-additional-namespace-to-point-to-the-modules-folde

Comment: You can check the mongodb module already to see the structure.

Answer (score 6):

The namespaces is based on PSR-4 autoload, check the specification http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4.

If you want to sub-modules, You can use the next folder structure.
d8:

```
/modules
   my_module/
     src/
      Controller/
        A.php
     modules/
       my_sub_module/
         src/
          Controller/
            B.php
```

The namespace for the "my_module":

```
Drupal\my_module\Controller\A
```

The namespace for the "my_sub_module":

`Drupal\my_sub_module\Controller\B`

See [PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625) for more information.

Comment: Thanks dmouse. Initially I posted my question on the linked resource on Drupal.org and now I have edited my own question to point to this thread as well ;)