# Can I register an additional namespace to point to the modules folder

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8 is it possible to register an additional namespace which points to the modules folder in addition to the \Drupal namespace?

e.g.: MyOwnNamespace\{module_name} to point to $path_to_module/src? I am asking this, because I would like to better understand how today's class design will affect my migration process to Drupal 8 one day.

This was a follow up question from [my original thread regarding namespacing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142248/drupal-8-sub-modules-sub-folders-and-how-to-namespace-classes).

As suggested by another user I split this off into a separate question thread, but the question has been answered in the original thread already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting my comment over there into a separate answer then ;)

You can, yes, see system_register() and drupal_classloader_register(). Those helper functions hardcode "Drupal\" as they are all about modules, but you could get the class_loader service directly.

As @Clive said there, I would not recommend doing it for your own classes, there isn't really a reason to do so, unless you're including an external library.

External libraries is a different story, that can be useful. As already commented in [How to autoload classes from a 3rd party PHP library in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/142247/how-to-autoload-classes-from-a-3rd-party-php-library-in-drupal-8), if you do not want to depend on [Composer Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/composer_manager), then you can implement your own autoloader service and register them either by [loading a composer-style autoload.php](https://github.com/amateescu/search_api_solr/blob/8.x-1.x/src/EventSubscriber/AutoloaderSubscriber.php), or if you have it available in a different way, by directly registering it in the cloassloader service.